# Vite + VueJS 3 + Bootstrap 5.2 - How to avoid importing Bootstrap scss file in all VueJS components?

Tags: vue.js, sass, bootstrap-5, vite

I'm currently building a VueJS 3 application using Vite and Bootstrap 5.2
I want to use reakpoint mixins in some of my components but I cannot manage to do it without having to import bootstrap .scss file in all of them.

I'd like to import it just once and be capable of using all bootstrap functions/mixins throughout the whole code.

```
This is what I have already tried (none of them worked for me):

1. Add `bootstrap` file import to `css > preProcessors > scss > additionalData` `vite.config.js` settings:
```

// vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 8080
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      find: '@vue/runtime-core',
      replacement: '@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js',
      '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap')
    }
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`
      }
    }
  }
})
```

2. Create a `./src/assets/styles.scss` file, import `bootstrap` in it and add it to `css > preProcessors > scss > additionalData` `vite.config.js` settings:

```
// vite.config.js (rest of settings equal to the one above)
css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import "./src/assets/styles.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
```

`./src/assets/styles.scss`

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

3. Import the same `./src/assets/styles.scss` file within `main.js` file
4. Import `bootstrap` file within `main.js`

---

Along with that I have a question: if I do the only thing that worked which is importing the `bootstrap` file on every Vue component I want: will it affect performance since (as far as I understand) bootstrap will be fully imported all of the times?

---

I'm more than happy to share any additional details of the project in order to try to get some answers.

Comment: Not an expert on BS but I'm not sure that you can import the CSS independently. This is also one of the drawbacks of using BS (with SASS), your aim is not towards performance but rather "bootstrapping" a quick solution (that is not meant to be long-term).

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to copy the `./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints.scss` file contents into a custom `./src/styles/_mixins.scss` file, and add this to the top of the file:

```css
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1400px
);
```

Without this, the file with the mixins wouldn't know about $grid-breakpoints. If you have set up bootstrap to use custom breakpoints then copy (or `@use '...' as *`) them instead.

Usage example:

```js
<template>
  <div class="test"> test </div>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
@use '@/styles/mixins' as mx;

.test {
  @include mx.media-breakpoint-down(lg) {
    color: red;
  }
}
</style>
```

I think it's one of the most optimal solutions that currently exist.

Answer (score 0):

you can insert this code in vite.config

```
 resolve: {
    alias: {
        '~bootstrap': path.resolve('node_modules/bootstrap'),
    }
},
```